# How to encode data off-chain and push to child storage trie on Substrate?

Tags: storage, runtime, storagemap

I am creating the reward pool concept that allows users to claim reward pool. For scalability, we used Child Storage trie for different pool as trie_index.

Each trie_index has [wallet, claimable_amount]. How do we add the claimable data of 100s of [wallet, claimable_amount] into child storage trie without inserting one by one?

I am curious, if there is a way we can encode an array of dictionary [wallet,claimable_amount] and then insert it into child trie.